# Android :Adding buttons dynamically in Asyn onPostExecute

Tags: android

I'm trying to call a method which generate Buttons dynamically onPostExecute method of AsyncTask.OnPostExecute the result can be something like S~D~W~H~H~A on Splitting Of this result.i need to create buttons dynamically.

```
private TextView textView;
        LinearLayout layout;
        Button btn;
        List<String> elements;  
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
             layout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutFor);

        }

        private class ExecuteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          @Override

            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
              String response = "";
              for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                  HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                  InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                  String s = "";
                  while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                  }          
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
              return response;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          elements = Arrays.asList(result.split("~"));  

                 generateButtonDynamically();
            }
          }
          public void onClick(View view) {
                    ExecuteTask task = new ExecuteTask ();
               task.execute(new String[] {"url"});
           }



      public void generateButtonDynamically()
        {

   for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

  LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutFor);
                    Button btn = new Button(this); 
                    btn.setText(elements.get(i)); 
                    linearLayout.addView(btn);  
            }



        }
```

In the generateButtonDynamically method.i am trying to generate the buttons dynamically and display.but it is not happening.

Answer (score 3):

Don't need to find id for ***LinearLayout*** again in ***onPostExecute()*** method. You have already globally declared.

And another thing set ***LayoutParams*** for Button and Check

```
       for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {

                Button btn = new Button(YourActivity.this); 
                btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT);
                btn.setText(elements.get(i)); 
                linearLayout.addView(btn);  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already found the `LinearLayout` in `onCreate()` by reference `layout`. Use the same in the method `generateButtonDynamically()`

Comment: yeah shree i did that too..,but not result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already solved. Try changing

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

in

```
Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
```

I think at that moment **this** points to *ExecuteTask* class instead of the *Context* that requires.
I had a similar problem and I solved it in this way.